# How do I pass data from a vue-resource method to my view layer in a vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-resource

I have a resource.js which is an ES6 class exported :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource)

export class Resource {

  getMovies () {
      // GET /someUrl
    return Vue.http.get('http://localhost:3335/cardname').then((response) => {
      console.log('success')
      return response
    }, (response) => {
      console.log('problem')
      return response
    })
  }

}
```

Then I am importing it in my component and passing the data in the in view/component:

```
<script>
  import { movies } from '../mock'
  import { Resource } from '../services/resource'
  const resourceService = new Resource()
  export default {
    name: 'hello',
    data () {
      return {
        msg: 'MovieRama',
        count: 0,
        movies: movies.movies,
        totalMovies: movies.total,
        test: null
      }
    },
    mounted: function () {
// Note this part
      let that = this
      resourceService.getMovies().then(function (result) {
        that.test = result
      })
    },
    methods: {
      boom: function () {
        console.log('Woho')
      },
      updateCount: function () {
        this.count++
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Please note the `mounted` method. Why do I need to keep the scope like that in order to pass data in data () { } ?

I am looking at the vue.js documentation and that doesn't seem necessary:

http://vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: Are you talking about the use of `let that=this` or the use of `resourceService`?

Comment: The use of let that = this, indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used an anonymous function, it has its' own scope when you call `this`.  If you use an arrow function you can get rid of that

```
resourceService.getMovies().then((result) => {
  this.test = result
})
```

I also recommend looking at the docs for creating resources: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/resource.md

This is a way to create a class that automatically has methods for `get`, `update`, `delete`, etc.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. It seems that my ESLINT checker doesn't allow arrow functions to return (for best practices reasons I presume)

Comment: Return statements are allowed in arrow functions.  If you simply need to return a value then you don't even need squiggly brackets.  ie. `Vue.http.get('/foo').then(response => response.body)` returns the body of the response so you can chain promises on that

Comment: actually the linter didn't allow setting values without { } around arrow functions :) so we're good.

Comment: ah yea, if you are going to use an expression you need the squigglies.  without them all you can do is return a simple value.